# "Data-loss while decompressing corrupted data" python threading

Tags: python, threadpool

I built a script to covert pdf files to excel and it works well. Now I want to use threading to make it faster but i keep getting this message "Data-loss while decompressing corrupted data" on the console and the output of my "extract" function are some random characters when I set the max_workers above 1

```
import os
import pdfplumber 
import pandas as pd
import glob
import re
import concurrent.futures

def extract(page):
    table = page.extract_table(table_settings={})
    tab=[]
    for rec in table:
        temp_rec=[]
        for field in rec:
            if field is not None:
                field = re.sub(r'\n|  +','', field)
                temp_rec.append(field)
        if temp_rec != header and len(temp_rec) == 8:
            tab.append(temp_rec)
    print(tab)
    return tab

header = ['Transaction Date', 'Description', 'InstCode', 'Value Date', 'Withdrawls', 'Deposits', 'Balance', '']

pdfs = glob.glob('*.pdf')
for file in pdfs:
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            result = executor.map(extract, pdf.pages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pdfplumber` module might be thread-unsafe, therefore, using it in multiple threads at the same time can lead to unexpected results, because of race conditions. In this case, it is a good idea to use a thread-Lock.

```
import os
import pdfplumber 
import pandas as pd
import glob
import re
import concurrent.futures
import threading
lock=threading.Lock()

def extract(page):
    lock.acquire()
    table = page.extract_table(table_settings={})
    if type(table)!=list and type(table)!=tuple:#I dont have any experience with pdfplumber, if this is an iterator, it will be converted to a tuple, because some Iterators might be thread-unsafe
        table=tuple(table)
    lock.release()
    tab=[]
    for rec in table:
        temp_rec=[]
        for field in rec:
            if field is not None:
                field = re.sub(r'\n|  +','', field)
                temp_rec.append(field)
        if temp_rec != header and len(temp_rec) == 8:
            tab.append(temp_rec)
    print(tab)
    return tab

header = ['Transaction Date', 'Description', 'InstCode', 'Value Date', 'Withdrawls', 'Deposits', 'Balance', '']

pdfs = glob.glob('*.pdf')
for file in pdfs:
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            result = executor.map(extract, pdf.pages)
```

Comment: Thanks. But why do I need to use lock there? is there a shared resource inside extract_table method? Is that what not being "thread-safe" means?

Comment: @Tony The page is a shared resource. I don't know what the internal shared object is, but it seems to be the only possible solution

Comment: each instance of the extract function is passed a separate page object to work with. right? "pdf.pages" is a list of page objects

Comment: @Tony yes, the objects they work with are different, but there seems to be an internal object all the different objects share, likely a file handle. When multiple threads access it at the same time, one thread might set the reading position to some place, to read data from the new position, while another thread doesn't expect this, and therefore reads the data from the new position, when it expected the data from the old position. Since this read process moved the pointer, the thread which set the pointer will read unexpected data too. The Data itself is valid, but is read incorrectly